# jQuery UI Resizable in React.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, reactjs

I have a react component in which I am trying to implement a jQuery ui resizable. I am pretty new to React.js and although the div does become draggable it does not become resizable.

Here is the code

```
export default class Element extends AppComponent {

  componentDidMount() {
    // store the node on the `this.node` so we can access elsewhere
    this.node = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this);

    //make self draggable
    $(this.node).draggable();
    //make self resizable
    $(this.node).resizable({
      handles: "n, e, s, w, ne, nw, se, sw",
      containment: 'parent',
      minHeight: "1px",
      minWidth: "1px",
      start: function(){},
      resize: function(){}
    });

  }

  render(){

    return(
      <div class="element-wrapper" style={this.props.elementStyle}>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Try to isolate your error, if you delete all your options is it working? (e.g. write only  $(this.node).resizable() )

Comment: no that did not work.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use jquery ui with React JS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38836553/how-to-use-jquery-ui-with-react-js)

Answer (score 0):

To use jQuery UI resizable you need to add the jQuery UI CSS file also.
include these two to work

```
https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css
https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js
```