# How to connect Threejs to React?

Tags: reactjs, three.js

I work with React and use a canvas. I want to change the canvas to WebGL (Threejs library). How to connect this library to React?

I have some element, e.g.

```
<div ref="threejs"></div>
```

How to make it a field for the Threejs library call? I don't want to use extensions like `react-threejs`.

Comment: In `componentDidMount` you can access the DOM reference `this.refs.threejs` and use something like `.appendChild(threeRenderer.domElement)`

Comment: Further reading on lifecycle methods like `componentDidMount`: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#the-component-lifecycle

Comment: Check out my answer how to map a 3rd party library in React: http://stackoverflow.com/a/40350880/1333836 Should look something similar in your case.

Answer (score 102):

Here is an example of how to set this up ([see demo](https://codepen.io/WebSeed/pen/MEBoRq)):

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import * as THREE from 'three'

class Scene extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)

    this.start = this.start.bind(this)
    this.stop = this.stop.bind(this)
    this.animate = this.animate.bind(this)
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    const width = this.mount.clientWidth
    const height = this.mount.clientHeight

    const scene = new THREE.Scene()
    const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(
      75,
      width / height,
      0.1,
      1000
    )
    const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({ antialias: true })
    const geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(1, 1, 1)
    const material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ color: '#433F81' })
    const cube = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material)

    camera.position.z = 4
    scene.add(cube)
    renderer.setClearColor('#000000')
    renderer.setSize(width, height)

    this.scene = scene
    this.camera = camera
    this.renderer = renderer
    this.material = material
    this.cube = cube

    this.mount.appendChild(this.renderer.domElement)
    this.start()
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    this.stop()
    this.mount.removeChild(this.renderer.domElement)
  }

  start() {
    if (!this.frameId) {
      this.frameId = requestAnimationFrame(this.animate)
    }
  }

  stop() {
    cancelAnimationFrame(this.frameId)
  }

  animate() {
    this.cube.rotation.x += 0.01
    this.cube.rotation.y += 0.01

    this.renderScene()
    this.frameId = window.requestAnimationFrame(this.animate)
  }

  renderScene() {
    this.renderer.render(this.scene, this.camera)
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div
        style={{ width: '400px', height: '400px' }}
        ref={(mount) => { this.mount = mount }}
      />
    )
  }
}

export default Scene
```

You might also be interested in a [full screen example](https://willbamford.github.io/react-with-threejs-example/) (see [GitHub](https://github.com/WebSeed/react-with-threejs-example)).

[Here's an example using React Hooks](https://codepen.io/WebSeed/pen/ZmXxKz) instead of a class.

Comment: Can you explain all the process to get the example running in a remote computer ? I just have knowledge about plain JavaScript. Thank you :)

Comment: Not binding the self (this) object to the animation function really caused issues before seeing this example.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [react-three-fiber](https://github.com/pmndrs/react-three-fiber)

```
npm install three @react-three/fiber
```

**Usage**

```
import React from 'react';
import React3 from 'react-three-renderer';
import * as THREE from 'three';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

class Simple extends React.Component {
  constructor(props, context) {
    super(props, context);

    // construct the position vector here, because if we use 'new' within render,
    // React will think that things have changed when they have not.
    this.cameraPosition = new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 5);

    this.state = {
      cubeRotation: new THREE.Euler(),
    };

    this._onAnimate = () => {
      // we will get this callback every frame

      // pretend cubeRotation is immutable.
      // this helps with updates and pure rendering.
      // React will be sure that the rotation has now updated.
      this.setState({
        cubeRotation: new THREE.Euler(
          this.state.cubeRotation.x + 0.1,
          this.state.cubeRotation.y + 0.1,
          0
        ),
      });
    };
  }

  render() {
    const width = window.innerWidth; // canvas width
    const height = window.innerHeight; // canvas height
    return (<React3
      mainCamera="camera" // this points to the perspectiveCamera which has the name set to "camera" below
      width={width}
      height={height}

      onAnimate={this._onAnimate}
    >
      <scene>
        <perspectiveCamera
          name="camera"
          fov={75}
          aspect={width / height}
          near={0.1}
          far={1000}
          position={this.cameraPosition}
        />
        <mesh
          rotation={this.state.cubeRotation}
        >
          <boxGeometry
            width={1}
            height={1}
            depth={1}
          />
          <meshBasicMaterial
            color={0x00ff00}
          />
        </mesh>
      </scene>
    </React3>);
  }
}
ReactDOM.render(<Simple/>, document.body);
```

Comment: `I don't want to use extensions like react-threejs`

Comment: Are there examples that would mutate the `Euler` object, rather than making a new instance every time there's a change?

Comment: @pailhead to notify react that state has changed, you must call the setState method. React compares the old value with the new value and if a change is detected, a new rendering occurs. The old and new comparison is "shallow" (not "deep" i.e. arrays and objects are compared by reference). The mutation of Euler would go undetected by React.

Comment: Note that the React setState method is is asynchronous. Updating the state based on the current state is not a good idea. see https://stackoverflow.com/a/48224805/731548 for proper way of doing this.

Comment: @cquezel one could store a more primitive value, for example - a timestamp of the last change. I believe that this would cause the change to be detected. Was wondering if there are any examples of this.

Answer (score 2):

## 2022 July Update

- React Hooks
- React Function Component
- WebGLRenderer.setAnimationLoop
- Typescript
- window resizing
- WebGL context disposal when unmounted

```js
import * as T from 'three';
import { useRef, useEffect, useCallback } from 'react';

class GL {
  scene: T.Scene = new T.Scene();
  renderer?: T.WebGLRenderer;
  camera?: T.PerspectiveCamera;
  width: number = 1;
  height: number = 1;
  destroyed: boolean = false;
  prevTime: number = 0;
  delta: number = 0;

  constructor() {}

  get aspect() {
    return this.width / this.height;
  }

  init ({ canvas, width, height }: Pick<GL, 'canvas' | 'width' | 'height'>) {
    this.width = width;
    this.height = height;
    this.camera = new T.PerspectiveCamera(70, this.aspect, 0.01, 10);
    this.camera.position.z = 3;
    this.scene.add(this.camera);

    /* ... place your objects here ... */
    this.scene.add(new T.AxisHelper(3));

    this.renderer = new T.WebGLRenderer({canvas});
    this.resize(width, height);
    this.renderer.setAnimationLoop(this.onLoop);
  }

  resize(width: number, height: number) {
    if (!this.camera || !this.renderer) return;
    this.camera.aspect = this.aspect;
    this.camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
    this.renderer.setSize(width, height);
    this.renderer.setPixelRatio(/* ... set your pixel ratio ... */);
  }

  onLoop: XRFrameRequestCallback = (time) => {
    if (!this.camera || !this.renderer) return;
    if (this.prevTime !== 0) this.delta = time - this.prevTime;
    /* do something with your delta and time */
    this.renderer.render(this.scene, this.camera);
    this.prevTime = time;
  };

  destroy() {
    this.renderer?.dispose();
    this.camera = undefined;
    this.destroyed = true;
  }
}

let gl = new GL();

const App: React.FC = () => {
  const refCanvas = useRef<HTMLCanvasElement>(null);

  const onResize = useCallback(() => {
    gl.resize(
      refCanvas.current.clientWidth,
      refCanvas.current.clientHeight
    );
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!refCanvas.current) return;
    const state = refCanvas.current;
    if (gl.destroyed) gl = new GL();
    gl.init({
      canvas: refCanvas.current,
      width: refCanvas.current.clientWidth,
      height: refCanvas.current.clientHeight,
    });
    window.addEventListener('resize', onResize);
    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener('resize', onResize);
      gl.destroy();
    };
  }, []);
  return <canvas ref={refCanvas} className="gl"></canvas>;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I have converted the first example of three.js to React thing.
Hope this is helpful
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';
import * as THREE from 'three';

```
class App extends React.Component{
  constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.scene = new THREE.Scene();
    this.camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75,
      window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight,
      0.1,
      1000
      );
    this.renderer = new THREE.WebGL1Renderer();
        this.renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
    this.geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry();
    this.material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: 0x32a852});
        this.cube = new THREE.Mesh( this.geometry, this.material)
  }
  animate = () => {
    requestAnimationFrame(this.animate)
    this.cube.rotation.x += 0.01;
    this.cube.rotation.y += 0.01;
    this.renderer.render(this.scene, this.camera);
    
  }
  componentDidMount() {
        document.body.appendChild( this.renderer.domElement );
        this.scene.add( this.cube );
        this.camera.position.z = 5;
        this.animate()
    }
  render(){
    return(
      <body id='document-body-01'>
      </body>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

So the idea is that the three components can be broken down to constructor, function of animate and componentdidmount.
I believe this.varname can be place anywhere.
I felt constructor was a good place.
This way other examples can be set as well.

Comment: When the component is unmounted, doesn't this leave a zombie element, renderer and RAF? Typically you need a `componentWillUnmount` cleanup handler as shown in the [more comprehensive, existing answer from 2017](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46412546/6243352). Also, I'd suggest using a ref so React can manage the parent element rather than `document.body.appendChild( this.renderer.domElement );` which circumvents React and indiscriminately attaches the canvas to the body. Using this approach, the connection with React is thin at best, doing more harm than good.

Answer (score -2):

I recommend you using the three fiber & three drei library.

Try to use `<Canvas></Canvas>` then, and you can speak to the canvas with React's `useRef` hooks.

https://docs.pmnd.rs/react-three-fiber/getting-started/introduction

The docs are very good to get started, make sure to check them out!

Comment: It would be good if you provide basic example in addition to the link posted.

Comment: OP specifically asked for solutions that don't use libraries.