# React applying JQuery code to an element inside a component

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, reactjs, bootstrap-wysiwyg

I have an application where I'm using React. I have a problem now where I'm trying to implement the [bootstrap-wysiwyg/bootstrap3-wysiwyg](https://github.com/bootstrap-wysiwyg/bootstrap3-wysiwyg/) package.

In order to get my `<textarea>` to work as the `ootstrap-wysiwyg/bootstrap3-wysiwyg` text editor I need to run the following JQuery function on the text editor:

```
$(".textarea").wysihtml5()
```

Here's my component:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'

export class MyTextEditor extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div className="form-group">
                <textarea className="textarea"></textarea>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

How can I apply that JQuery function to my `<textarea>` in the React component?

I know it's not very good practice to blend React and JQuery but I really need this to work. If there is an alternative method to getting the package to work I would appreciate that as an answer instead.

Otherwise if anyone can help me get this to work it would be much appreciated!

**Update:** *(Still looking)*

Thanks for all the suggestions. I've tried a bunch but they've all led to problems:

1. `<ReactQuill>` just doesn't display well at all, buttons are gigantic.
2. `<EditableDiv>` gives me: `Uncaught Error: addComponentAsRefTo(...): Only a ReactOwner can have refs.`
3. Syam Mohan's answer gives me: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'font-styles' of undefined at f`

Still in search for something that will work, thank you for all the efforts so far!

Comment: I'd take a look at any [react versions](https://github.com/sonyan/react-wysiwyg-editor) first and see if you can use them or not.

Comment: Please take a look to https://github.com/zenoamaro/react-quill .

Comment: I had some trouble implementing `<ReactQuill />`. I should mention that my text editor is appearing on a modal.  The `ReactQuill` buttons are giant.

Comment: @MartinMazzaDawson using `<EditableDiv>` gave me the following error:

`Uncaught Error: addComponentAsRefTo(...): Only a ReactOwner can have refs.`

Not sure where that comes from, but basically if I use `<EditableDiv>` the error occurs, if not my app runs without error.

Comment: When a library modifies the DOM, we try to keep React out of it's way. You need to create a component to manage the jQuery plugin, mostly by using the `componentDidMount`/`componentWillUnmount` to initialize/destroy the third party library. See my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/40350880/1333836

Comment: Regarding the use of Syam Moram's answer you can clear up the 'font-styles' error by switching to the bootstrap3-wysiwyg-commonjs fork of the boostrap-wysiwyg package: https://github.com/sharathprabhal/bootstrap3-wysiwyg-commonjs . See https://github.com/bootstrap-wysiwyg/bootstrap3-wysiwyg/issues/207

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To add and import JQuery is the **first part**.

1) Using `webpack` the best way I saw was to add a plugin in your `webpack.config.js`:

```
var webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
    plugins: [
        new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
            '$': 'jquery',
            'jQuery': 'jquery',
            'window.jQuery': 'jquery'
        })
    ]
};
```

All these different typos are here to make JQuery availability compatible with all kinds of modules.
Of course you need to `npm install` `jquery` and your plugin (`wysihtml5`).

2) Or you could import it in your `index.html`:
`<script src="jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>`

EDIT: 3) Using meteor I did `meteor add jquery` and that did the trick.

Then, **second part** is to use it in React.

To use a jquery plugin on an element you need it to be rendered first, that's why you need to put the code in `componentDidMount` (which is run after the first render).
And I would advise you (based on my different search when I had to do the same thing as you but with `bootstrapTable`) to make the render part the most simple (by removing ) and to use `ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this)` as a selector for JQuery:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'

export class MyTextEditor extends Component {

    componentDidMount() {
        $(ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this)).wysihtml5()
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <textarea className="textarea"></textarea>
        )
    }
}
```

EDIT: Or to use React's `refs`

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'

export class MyTextEditor extends Component {

    componentDidMount() {
        $(this.refs.textareaIWantToUse).wysihtml5()
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="form-group">
                <textarea className="textarea" ref="textareaIWantToUse"></textarea>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm using Meteor so it's a bit different, the `<textarea>` is apart of a form so I'd prefer to keep it in the component that I set it in.

Comment: I edited the post accordingly, I add this issue with meteor too

Comment: I shall let you know once I've checked that this solution works.

Comment: So this updated answer gives me the following error:

`Exception from Tracker recompute function: TypeError: $(...).wysihtml5 is not a function`

Comment: Which scripts are you including in your project / html ? 
On https://github.com/jhollingworth/bootstrap-wysihtml5 it says to add `wysihtml5`, `jquery`, `bootstrap` and `bootstrap-wysihtml5`, one of them could be missing.

Comment: Ah of course, I forgot that I took them out while testing the other answer.  Will get back to you shortly.

Comment: Ah this gives me the same error that I got trying Syam's answer: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'font-styles' of undefined at f`

Comment: Well then I don't know at all, it must be related to that plugin, did you made it worked somewhere else ?

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import $ from 'jquery'; 

export class MyTextEditor extends Component {

  componentDidMount() {
    $(".textarea").wysihtml5()
  }

  render() {
    return (
        <div className="form-group">
            <textarea className="textarea"></textarea>
        </div>
     )
  }
}
```

**NOTE:** Do not forget to add JQuery library

Comment: Syam Mohan, can you explain how to add jQuery library to React app? Thanks.

Comment: Doing that gives me the following error in the console: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'font-styles' of undefined at f `

Comment: how to add jQuery library to React app? - `import $ from jquery`. But this is not good approach. Please see my comment below OP post

Comment: You can clear up the 'font-styles' error by switching to the bootstrap3-wysiwyg-commonjs fork of the boostrap-wysiwyg package: https://github.com/sharathprabhal/bootstrap3-wysiwyg-commonjs . See https://github.com/bootstrap-wysiwyg/bootstrap3-wysiwyg/issues/207