# Utilizing Jquery UI into React Component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, leaflet

I am trying to follow this tutorial for drag n' drop.

https://georepublic.info/en/blog/2012/leaflet-example-with-wfs-t/

I want to build this out using react, but see they are using jquery ui and the draggable functionality. I'm confused as to how I would import and call this same thing via a react component. Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: This might help. A gist of someone integration jQuery UI (Sortable) in React: https://gist.github.com/petehunt/7882164

Comment: See my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/40350880/1333836 You need to create a component to manage the jQuery UI, mostly by using the `componentDidMount`/`componentWillUnmount` to initialize/destroy the jQuery UI plugin. I also [wrote an article explaining the approach I use in more details](https://medium.com/@superKalo/how-to-use-jquery-libraries-in-the-react-ecosystem-7dfeb1aafde0).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use jquery ui with React JS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38836553/how-to-use-jquery-ui-with-react-js)