# JQuery in ReactJS: TypeError: jquery__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_18___default(...)(...).sortable is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs

I'm trying to implement JQuery in the react for sorting (dragging) the  (components) in the ReacJS.

I'm hitting the error of :

> TypeError:
> jquery__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_18___default(...)(...).sortable is not
> a function

I'm have tried to solve but nothing helps me.
Please help me to rectify this.

My code as follows:

index.html

```
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

AllComponets.js

```
import React from "react";
import Widget1 from "./Widget1";
import Widget2 from "./Widget2";
import Widget3 from "./Widget3";
import Component5 from "./Component5";
import $ from "jquery";

export default class  AllComponents extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    $(function () {
      $("#sortable").sortable({
        revert: true,
      });
    });
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div id="sortable">
          <Component5 />
          <Widget1 />
          <Widget2 />
          <Widget3 />
         </div>
        </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: This might help you https://github.com/SortableJS/Sortable/issues/1076

Comment: Does this help https://stackoverflow.com/a/40350880/12610347 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me -

install `npm i jquery-ui-bundle`

and add in your component

```
import $ from 'jquery';
import 'jquery-ui-bundle';
import 'jquery-ui-bundle/jquery-ui.min.css';
```