# How to use Zebradatepicker in Reactjs?

Tags: reactjs, rxjs

Here I am trying to use Zebradatepicker in my reactjs application. Below is the sample code I am trying to execute in onclick function of react application.

$("#datepicker_start").Zebra_DatePicker({ format: 'm-d-Y' });

Below is the error which i see.

TypeError: jquery__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_3___default(...)(...).Zebra_DatePicker is not a function

So i wanted to use Zebradatepicker in react application.

Comment: You should try and avoid jQuery in ReactJS. But if you really want to use it, you'd put it in componentDidMount()
and then initialize Zebra Date picker

Comment: @RadiantAhmed yes doing with the same approach but it is throwing this error

Comment: are you using cdn or you installed jquery library and even installed zebra date picker

Comment: i am using installed jquery library and zebra date picker

Answer (score 0):

first you install jquery

```
npm install jquery
```

secondly you have to install zebra

```
npm i zebra_datepicker
```

thirdly you have to work with zebra

```
window.$ = window.jQuery = require('jquery')
```

fourthly you have to do this

Import the loader into your root file before you import the files which require jquery
app.js

```
import 'pathToYourZebra/zebra_datepicker.js'
```

Comment: I am able to use jquery but the problem is with zebra_datepicker(https://github.com/stefangabos/Zebra_Datepicker ).Here that is not able to use with jquery

Comment: @RiteshTiwari you can try https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-datepicker this if its not compulsory to use zebra really sorry didnt know why zebra is not working at your side even here is another example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38836553/how-to-use-jquery-ui-with-react-js/40350880#40350880