# Make element Hide towards center , React.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs

I'm trying to hide my element towards center like this example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/TzzxZ/1/). I'm using react.js and somehow this jQuery code isn't working.

```
$('#img-funder-logo').hide('scale', { percent: 0 }, 1000).fadeIn(2000);
```

Any reason why this won't work with react? How can I go about doing it?

Comment: Note that the `scale` modifier relies on jQueryUI which has also been added to the Fiddle you link to. Make sure that's referenced in your code as well

Comment: Hi, How do I go about referencing that

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/38836553/519413

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So An easy way to achieve this without going through setting up `jquery-ui`,
you just need to align the item you fading center using css/scss , in this case it was an image `text-align: center`